# Angular: Pass variables to window.open();

Tags: angular

I would like to open a new tab in Angular that won't have any functions at all. It is only a tab to display data for a user to print. My problem is that in the main app I do a call to get the data, but when I open the new tab, the variables don't hold the data from the main app. The variables are reset as if it is a new instance of the Angular app.

I create a new tab by doing the following:

```
window.open('#/print-report');
```

Then in my app modules the above route opens the PrintReportComponent:

```
{ path: 'print-report', component: PrintReportComponent},
```

But in the new tab, every variable throughout my program is reset to its default value when the app starts up. How do I "save" or "pass" any variables to this new tab?

Comment: use the `localStorage` which holds values on a domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

To print report:

```
  /**
   * Method is used to print report.
   * @param response - html response.
   */
  printReport(response) {

    let data = response;

    let Pagelink = "about:blank";

    let pwa = window.open(Pagelink, "_new");

    if (!pwa || pwa.closed || typeof pwa.closed == 'undefined') {

      alert('Pop-up!', 'Please disable your Pop-up blocker and try again.', 'warning');

    }

    pwa.document.open();

    pwa.document.write(data);

    pwa.print();

  }
```

To download report:

```
    /**
     * Method is use to download file.
     * @param data - Array Buffer data
     * @param type - type of the document.
     */
    downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type.toString() });
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(url);
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible somehow to add a css library into that new page?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a service that let you get your data and then make sure to identify your data by id in the url, then you can do this in the new tab component in ngOnInit:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((param: any) => {
            this.functionThatGivesYouData(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id);
        });
```

So now you can make new request to same data by id. otherwise you should use localstorage which is not safe if you're holding confidential information.

Answer (score 0):

Just use local storage, as commented by @trichetriche

Comment: but in this way you need to store data

Comment: as answer i have given you can direct pass data to method to print and down load no need to use local storage