# angular : how to show data in new tab by rendering a component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

here is the complete scenario,

I have a ag-grid, now I am doing double click on one of the row and getting that data.

```
rowDoubleClicked(row) {
    this.service.detail(this.a, row[this.a], this.detail).subscribe((data) => {

      // here i am able to get the data which is coming from backend.

      this.service.data.next(data); // via this I am sending the data to detail component

      window.open("detailComponent", "_blank");  // opening the detail component in different tab
    });

  }
```

detail component

```
constructor(private service: Service) {
    this.service.data.subscribe((data) => {
      this.data= data;
      alert("a"); //  it is also not working
      debugger;
    });

  }
```

html file

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue">
    {{item}}
    {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
  </div>
  abc{{data}}    // html page only showing abc
```

service file

```
readonly data = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
```

as per the logic detail component should show the data which I am sending on double click of ag-grid. but it is showing only the data which is static in nature.

so basically how to send the data on new tab in angular.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to send data from one tab to another.

**1.LocalStorage**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

To Set data

```
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(value));
```

To Get data

```
this.obj= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
```

To Remove data

```
   localStorage.removeItem('key');
```

**2. window.postMessage()**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Additionally,but not sure

window.document.write()
[Angular: Pass variables to window.open();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592877/angular-pass-variables-to-window-open)